# MVC C# Move item from DropDownList to <select>

Tags: c#, jquery, asp.net, asp.net-mvc, html

I'm new to MVC and am learning how it works from WebForms. In my current project I need to take data from a DropdownList that I'm filling from a database and passing via viewbag and when the "Add" submit is clicked, it adds the dropdown's selected item to a  (or ListBox) and when the "remove" submit is pushed, it removes the selected item in the  (or ListBox). My Code is:

```
@Html.DropDownList("systemlist", "Select a System")
<br />
<input type = "submit" class="btn btn-xs btn-primary" name="button_addsystem" value="Add" />
<input type = "submit" class="btn btn-xs btn-primary" name="button_removesystem" value="Remove" />
<br />
<select size = "4" id="systems_list" class="list-group" style="height:100px;width:200px;">
</select>
```

I am used to web forms where it would trigger a refresh and a server side event to do this and I'm struggling to relate anything in tutorials or other questions to what I am trying to do

Comment: Your `<select>` element does not even have a `name` attribute and does not bind to anything so its not clear what the purpose this is. And you can easily do move the options using javascript (calling a controller method is not necessary)

Comment: @StephenMuecke so would you say UI events such as moving data around and other visual things is best to be done via JS? Because if so that actually helps me out a lot. I have just been looking at it wrong

Comment: You will get far better performance - something like `$('#add').click(function() { var selected = $('#systemlist option:selected'); $('#systems_list').append(selected); });` when the button is `<button type="button" id="add">Add</button>`